# Confused about subspaces of functions

Tags: linear-algebra

I find that subspaces of vectors makes sense, but I'm having trouble with the following problem involving a function:

Let $a$ be a real number and consider the following subset of $C[-1,1]$:
   $$F := \{f(x) \in C[-1,1]: f(0) = a\} $$
For which values of $a$ is $F$ a subspace of $C[-1,1]$? If $F$ is a subspace, prove it.

I am really confused on how to solve this. I understand that with vectors, one criteria for being a subspace is containing the zero vector. Would this be the same as this function needing to go through the origin so that $f(0)=0$? Thank you!

Comment: Note that the constant function $g(x)=a$ is in $F$.  Is $g + g$ in $F$?

Comment: Wouldn't it be since it still remains from -1<=x<=1?

Comment: What's $(g+g)(0)$?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be 2a, which if a=0 just be 0?

Comment: Yep, exactly!  So which $a$'s do give you a subspace?

Comment: Would it only be for a=0 then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zero vector of your space is the function $x \mapsto 0$. We know that it must be contained in that set in order for it to be a subspace. And since this set contains functions $f$ only such that $f(0) = a$ we have that $a$ must be $0$ in order for it to be a candidate subspace.

Now is it really a subspace? Yes because not only the zero vector is there but also for all vectors $f,g$ and any scalar $\lambda$ we have
$$ (f + g)(0) = f(0) + g(0) = 0 \implies f+g \in F$$
$$ (\lambda f)(0) = \lambda f(0) = 0 \implies \lambda f \in F $$

Hence $F$ is subspace only if $a=0$.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. Let's say the specification that f(0)=a was not necessary in F. In this case, could a be any number?

Comment: What do you mean by the specification that $f(0)=a$ was not necessary in $F$? Because if we drop that then the set $F = \left\{ f \in C[-1,1]\right\}$ is the entire space.